# intento ejecutar un código python mediante un sistema en C# asp.net, pero me da error por la librería

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, pywhatkit

Quiero ejecutar un código en python para enviar mensajes por WhatsApp, seguí un tutorial en YouTube, pero al momento de usar la función, el programa me bota el siguiente error "No module named pywhatkit"

Código en python

```
#librerías
import pywhatkit 
from datetime import datetime

#Codigo
def Mensaje(numero="+9999999999", mensaje="Mensaje"):
  try: 
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(numero, mensaje, datetime.now().hour, datetime.now().minute + 1, 15, True, 5)     
  except: 
    print("Ha ocurrido un error!")
```

Código en C# asp.net

```
try
        {
            string numero = "+99999999999", mensaje = "Mesaje desde el sistema en C# asp.NET";
            //aqui se le da la ruta del archivo python a ejecutar
            string rutaArchivoPython = Server.MapPath(@"~\ModGestionEconomico\Reportes\Whatsapp\EnviarMensaje.py");
            
            ScriptRuntime py = Python.CreateRuntime();
            
            dynamic whatsapp = py.UseFile(rutaArchivoPython);

            whatsapp.Mensaje(numero, mensaje);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Lo curioso es que si funciona cuando ejecuto solo el código python en Visual Code, pero al hacerlo mediante el sistema en C# asp.NET, me aparece el error en el try catch "No module named pywhatkit"

no entiendo por qué me sale ese error si ya tengo instalado esa librería.

Comment: Estas trabajando en un entorno virtual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las librerias que instalas las ejecuta un usuario que tiene permisos para acceder a ellas, y el usuario .NET no tiene permisos, mi consejo, compila el codigo en un exe para que se ejecute todo en un entorno virtual ya que no es posible levantar un entorno virtual en VS o almenos es mas complicado que generar un archivo .exe de python